# Transit visa requirement for Indian citizen with US permanent residence travelling from Delhi-Frankfurt-London-Chicago

Tags: visas, air-travel

My wife is Indian citizen with us permanent residence. She would be travelling from Delhi-Frankfurt_London-Chicago with small layovers at London and Frankfurt. As Germany is Schengen and London is non-Schengen, would she still need transit/visitor visa? I know for Indian citizens with US residency, transit visa is not required if there is a single layover in Europe. Also visa is required if there is more tahn one Schengen lay over. What about this one Schengen and one non-Schengen layover?

If I need a transit/visitor visa, do I need for Germany or UK or both?

Comment: She would then be OK as far as the Schengen area is concerned. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27386/transit-visa-requirement-montreal-to-tehran-via-london-and-frankfurt and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30197/transit-visa-requirements-while-traveling-from-us-to-india-with-stops-in-heathro

Answer (score 1):

That's almost the same situation than [Transit visa requirements while traveling from US to India with stops in Heathrow and Frankfurt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30197/transit-visa-requirements-while-traveling-from-us-to-india-with-stops-in-heathro/30591#30591) except your wife is a permanent resident in the US.

Just as in the other case, she would be exempted from any airport transit visa requirement in the Schengen area based on her permanent resident status in the US. As London is not in the Schengen area, the flight will depart from the international part of the airport and visa-free transfer should be possible. See also [Transit visa travelling from Canada to India via Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/transit-visa-travelling-from-canada-to-india-via-germany) or [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area/30570)

In the UK, she would also be exempted from the direct airside transit visa requirement based on her status in the US, if she holds a “US permanent residence card issued on or after 21 April 1998”. See [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no)